# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution:' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair.. Any solutions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, code-signing

I'm in the process of writing and deployment of my first iOS application. When I tried to build release build (flavour) of my project for real iOS device (I select `Release` in project schema and choose `Products->Archive`). I got an error as in the question title. Trying googling I found that it's a very popular error and only on stackoverflow there are nearly four threads for it. But trying to follow advices listed there changed nothing.
I tried to change certificate keys preferences (code signing identity) in the Targets->Build Settings in different ways. I also tried to change them directly via `xcodebuild`. Eventualy, I've tried all the combinations (developer/distribution). May be this settings even don't relate to this problem - i don't know.
So the question is there some exact solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to distribute this on the app store already? Or just want to build on your phone?

Comment: Off course his trying to put the app on the App Store. His trying to archive it. Please read the question carefully before answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when I upgraded to xcode 4.5 iOS 6. Just go to organizer and select profiles and when you see your distribution click on it and remove it. Then try to refresh. It will connect to developer site and download your current distribution profile. Then when trying to choose your profile in your project you can see the new set of profiles which will work. Just make sure your distribution profile is current. That should so it.
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

Found another esoteric thing that needs to be checked if you're still getting this error after having tried everything. Make sure the code signing selections under TARGETS->Build Settings isn't overriding what you've set for code signing in PROJECT->Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

This error came up for me because I did not have scheme setup in debug mode.

1. Option Click on the run button pops upa window in which you should be selecting 'Debug' for "Build Configuration".